# An abelian group proof with $g*g=e$ for all $g$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, monoid

I have to show that the following group
$$ (G, * , e) $$
with its operation $*$, which is defined through $ g*g = e$  for every $g \in G $ is an abelian group.

In order to do that one have only to show that the group is commutative.

How can one prove it whereas the operation is defined always between an Element and itself?

I reckon it is not so simple as it seems

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: That $g*g = e$ for all $g ∈ G$ means that $g = g^{-1}$ for all $g ∈ G$. What is $(g*h)^{-1}$ in general for $g, h ∈ G$?

Comment: @k.stm is it allowed to square with a defined operation, which is not multiplication? And as I understand that one can not really describe gh or hg with this operation

Comment: @Ozk The operation is not _defined_ by $g^2 = e$ for every $g$, because then you would not have defined $gh$ in general for $g, h \in G$. Instead, the operation has the _property_ that $g^2 = e$ for every $g$.

Comment: It doesn't matter *what* * is.  All that matters is it *is* a binary operation.  So $hg$ is *something*  It could be $hg= j$ or $hg=babar\ the\ elephant$.  But the *property* is that $g*g = e$ for all $g$ so $(hg)*(hg) = e$.  Meant $(hg)^{-1} = hg$.

Comment: Not $hg*gh = h(gg)h = heh = hh = e$.  But $hg*hg = e$ so ....... $hg*gh = hg*hg$ so .....

Answer (score 0):

Consider $$(a\ast b)\ast (a\ast b)=e=(a\ast a)\ast(b\ast b)$$ then cancel $a$ on the left and $b$ on the right.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your actual question.

When the book says $*$ is *defined* to be that $g*g=e$ for all $g\in G$, the book is abusing language.  That isn't the *definition* of $*$; it is a property (a *very* significant property) of $*$ but not the *definition* of $*$.

If $G$, the set, is $\{e,a,b,c,d,e,f,g\}$ for example we know that $a*a=e$ and $c*c = e$ but we don't know what $ab$ is equal to;  It could by $ab = c$ or it could be $ab = f$.  But it doesn't matter.

......

We can prove that for all $a,b \in G$ that whatever $ab$ is equal to, that $ba$ must also be equal to the same value.

Note that if $ab = k$ and $k*k = e$ we have $(ab)(ab) = e$.  But we also have $(ab)(ba) = a(bb)a = aea =aa = e$.  So we have both $(ab)(ab) = e$ and $(ab)(ba) = e$.

If we rely on the proof we should have proven earlier that inverses are unique that means that $ab = (ab)^{-1}$ and $ba = (ab)^{-1}$ so $ab = ba$.

.....

If we want to *really* convince ourselves and we don't mind reinventing the wheel:

> $(ab)(ab) = e$

> $(ab)(ab)(ba) = (ba)$

> $(ab)a(bb)a = ba$

> $(ab)aa = ba$

> $(ab) = ba$

=====

The thing is that other than examples to teach the concept of groups the actual operation $*$ doesn't matter and we almost never *define* what $a*b$ is equal to. And if $ab = c$ or $ab=f$ it won't matter.  That's just labelling.  What matters is only certain properties.